# Using fancyBox inside InfoBubble.js with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I can't seem to get [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to load inside the [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/) (i.e., my info window). I have a button inside the InfoBubble, which when clicked, should display an image using fancyBox. I have come across previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757583/fancybox-infowindow-google-map) and few others, but none of those solutions worked for me.

The way I have it set up is as follows. In `index.html`:

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script src="map.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="infobubble.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dialog").fancybox({ width: '50%', height: '50%', closeClick: true });
});    
</script>
```

In `map.js`:

```
infoBubble = new InfoBubble({
        maxWidth: 200,
        content: '<a class="dialog" href="preview.jpg" target="_blank">
                  <img src="button-icon.png"/></a>',
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoBubble.open(map, marker);
```

By referencing the CSS class `.dialog`, shouldn't it work because the script is already there in the `index.html` page? It doesn't work. Instead I am just redirected to the image in a new page.

Comment: The content in the infoBubble isn't rendered (can't be found in the DOM) until the infowindow is opened.  You haven't provided that code.

Comment: @geocodezip Sorry, I've just added that (see edits). It's associated with an event listener for the marker. I see the content inside the InfoBubble. It appears fine. Just fancyBox doesn't work.

Comment: You need to wait for the domready event of the InfoBubble to fire before running  this `$(".dialog").fancybox({ width: '50%', height: '50%', closeClick: true });`

Comment: @geocodezip Where should I place that line of code to make that happen? How do I figure out where the domready event of InfoBubble is? Apologies for too many questions, I'm still a beginner in JS so a bit unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the domready event of the InfoBubble to fire before running this:

```
$(".dialog").fancybox({ width: '50%', height: '50%', closeClick: true });
```

[example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B5fF2/)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infoBubble.open(map, marker);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infoBubble, 'domready', function () {
        $(".dialog").fancybox({
            width: '200px',
            height: '200px',
            closeClick: true
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I am using Firefox, and it does not seem to be working in your JSFiddle either. The image opens in a new window rather than inside fancyBox.

Comment: That is what your code does. `content: '<a class="dialog" href="preview.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="button-icon.png"/></a>'`, if you don't want it to do that, change it (particularly the target="_blank").

Comment: That line of code should open the image in fancyBox, shouldn't it? Like in this forked fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9vh6p/1/ (see the button below map). This is not happening inside infoBubble.

Comment: Sorry, see http://jsfiddle.net/9vh6p/2/. I forgot to remove `target="_blank"`. Regardless, there's still an issue though. Thanks for all your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and I got it to work like this.

You'll need to add an event listener to the domready event as suggested by geocodezip, but with some modifications.  Simply opening fancybox from with the domready event doesn't seem to work.  I'm not sure why not.

From lots of fiddling, I was able to figure out that adding the code to the onclick event seemed to do it.  Note that the onclick event handler has two statments.  The first opens the fancybox.  The second returns a false to the onclick event handler.  Without that, page redirects immediately after the fancybox loads.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    infoBubble.open(map, marker);
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(infoBubble, 'domready', function () {

        var thecode = "$.fancybox.open([{href : 'preview.jpg', type : 'iframe'}]); return false;";

        $(".dialog").attr('onclick', thecode);

    });
});
```